# How to activate JavaScript "onclick" Event via Excel VBA?

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I'm trying to click on a button on a webpage via a VBA excel script, but I'm getting runtime errors when using the below code:

```
objIE.document.getElementById("e-actions-commonmasthead-mail").Click
```

The element I'm trying to get from the page is listed with the following HTML:

```html
<td id="e-actions-commonmasthead-mail"
    class="s-cell-center s-toolbarcell-left s-toolbar-text s-toolbarcell-selected" 
    title="Mail" toolbarside="left" toolbarindex="0" 
    com_ibm_dwa_ui_toolbar_overflowed="false"

 onmouseover="AAA.DSq.EKc.prototype.EYl['e-actions-commonmasthead:Ebx'].EEu(event, this);"
  onmouseout="AAA.DSq.EKc.prototype.EYl['e-actions-commonmasthead:Ebx'].EEu(event, this);"
     onclick="AAA.DSq.ELU(event, 'e-actions-commonmasthead', 'Gqj', {area:'mail'});" 

  unselectable="on" style="-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-user-select:none;">

<img align="center" border="0" width="16" height="16" 
     id="e-actions-commonmasthead-mail-icon" 
     class="s-toolbaricon-notext" 
     src="/iNotes/Forms9.nsf/transparent.gif?OpenFileResource&amp;MX&amp;TS=20160816T154745,21Z" 
     xoffset="" yoffset="" 
     style="background-image: url(&quot;/iNotes/Forms9.nsf/sprite_masthead.png?OpenFileResource&amp;MX&amp;TS=20160816T154745,21Z&quot;); 
            background-position: -17px 0px;">
</td>
```

I've tried both Click and FireEvent "onclick" and they give me runtime errors.

Comment: What are the errors you're getting though?

Comment: I'm getting Run Time error '424', Object required.

Comment: Check each of the objects in the line of code you posted to see which one is `Nothing`.  Posting a bit more code would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. I need to call the onclick script manually via below code:

```
 Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("AAA.DSq.ELU(event, 'e-actions-commonmasthead', 'Gqj', {area:'mail'})", "JavaScript")
```

Thanks for all the help and hints!